# Adding a RestAPI to a Xamarin .NetStandard 2.0 Shared Class Library

Tags: c#, xamarin

As you are probably aware, Microsoft has deprecated the Portable Class Library (PCL) in Xamarin and replaced it with the .Net Standard class library instead.

I have a couple of older Xamarin projects that use a PCL, but I have started a new project using the .Net Standard class library this week.

Each project needs access to a RestAPI.

A RestAPI could be added to the PCL projects through an easy to use menu as below, and generate the client for me. The .Net Standard project is missing this menu.

**Does anyone know how to get this menu back or another way to generate the RestAPI for the .Net Standard projects?**

The API for this new project is likely to expand very quickly and change frequently, at least in the early days of development so I wish to avoid having to write it myself (as the Xamarin guide on their site suggests doing).

I am currently using AutoRest to generate the API classes and models to use in Xamarin but i feel this is only a work around as currently to get it to generate correctly I had to use an old version of AutoRest (0.13.0) and an old version of Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime(1.8.0) which i copied from a completely different project and run with a BatchFile pointed to a .json file generated from the api.

PCL
[image: PCL Menu]

.Net Standard
[image: .Net Standard Menu]